# How to add React component to a website using babel

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying to add a React component to a website using `babel`. Here's official React documentation [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) but I could not make it work.

Here's my `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
    <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="build/index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my `src/index.js`

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'

function App() {
    return (
        <button>Like me!</button>
    )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

Here's my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "react-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6"
  }
}
```

Then I run in terminal:

```bash
./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-dir build --presets @babel/preset-react
```

It creates `build/index.js` which is added to my `index.html`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
function App() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("button", null, "Like me!");
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render( /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(App, null));
```

When I open `index.html` in browser - nothing happens, button does not appear.

This whole story works only if I add `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>` to my `index.html` but this is not what I want.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

because babel only compiles jsx the `esm` syntax remains and you have nothing to deal with them (a compiler or esm itself with `type='module'` and cdn esm or importmap)

for starters use powerful tools like [vite](https://vitejs.dev)